# How to find longest length array within an array of an object?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, filter

I am trying to come up with a single function that returns the object with the longest length array within an array.

Here is the question:

5. Write a function that lists all the Orcs that have the most the weapons.

Example:

```
var orcs = [{
    name: 'Orgoth',
    strength: 9001,
    weapons: ['Bone ax', 'Mace of Strength']
}, {
    name: 'Blaroguhh',
    strength: 500,
    weapons: ['Cheeseburger', 'Spear of the Hut']
}, {
    name: 'Mark',
    strength: 543,
    weapons: ['Ax of Defense', 'Dagger', 'Sword']
}]
getMostWeapons(orcs);
// =>   {name: 'Mark', strength: 543, weapons: ['Ax of Defense', 'Dagger', 'Sword' ]}
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
function getMostWeapons(orcs) {
    var length = 0;
    return orcs.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj.filter(function (val) {
            if (val.length > length) {
                return (length = val.length);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: `filter` isn't the proper function for this. It returns all the elements that the function returns true for.

Comment: What if there are multiple objects with same max length?

Comment: I am open to all solutions

Comment: @Tushar I would want the function to return all objects with the max length in that case

Comment: Why the nested `.filter()`? Within the outer filter function you can test `obj.weapons.length`. (Though as has been pointed out, filter isn't the right way to go, and you need to decide how to handle more than one orc with the same number of weapons.)

Comment: I tried this but couldn't get it to output the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` is used to return all the array elements that match a criteria. Since you don't know the maximum length until you've gone through all the orcs, you can't use it in one pass to find the orc to return.

Just use an ordinary loop that compares the length of weapons to the longest seen so far. If it's longer, replace the longest with this one.

```
function getMostWeapons(orcs) {
    var longest = 0;
    var longestOrcs = [];
    orcs.forEach(function(orc) {
        if (orc.weapons.length > longest) {
            longestOrcs = [orc];
            longest = orc.weapons.length;
        } else if (orc.weapons.length == longest) {
            longestOrcs.push(orc);
        }
    });
    return longestOrcs;
}
```

Comment: Did you read my comment. _"What if there are multiple objects with same max length?"_ and OP's reply on it _"I would want the function to return all objects with the max length in that case"_

Comment: @Tushar I had some `longestOrc` that I didn't change to `longestOrcs` when changing to return an array. It works now.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter()` isn't really what you want here because you wouldn't know what you were filtering for without first making a pass to see what the max length was.  `.reduce()` could be used (for side effects), but you aren't really accumulating a single value here like `.reduce()` is built for.  So, it makes sense to just use `.forEach()` with a couple parent-scoped variables to keep track of our state.

To return all objects that have the max length, you can do this (in a snippet you can run to see the results).  This returns an array of all objects that have the maximum length.

```js
var orcs = [{
  name: 'Orgoth',
  strength: 9001,
  weapons: ['Bone ax', 'Mace of Strength']
}, {
  name: 'Blaroguhh',
  strength: 500,
  weapons: ['Cheeseburger', 'Spear of the Hut']
}, {
  name: 'Mark',
  strength: 543,
  weapons: ['Ax of Defense', 'Dagger', 'Sword']
}];

function getMostWeapons(o) {
  var max = 0, maxObj = [];

  o.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.weapons.length > max) {
      max = item.weapons.length;
      maxObj = [item];
    } else if (item.weapons.length === max) {
      maxObj.push(item);
    }
  });

  return maxObj;
}

var max = getMostWeapons(orcs);
log(max);

function log(x) {
  document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
}
```

Comment: This is great because it takes into account if there is more than one answer. Thank you!

Comment: @xgrioux if wanna test shorter version you can check my answer

Comment: This is great!! I wish I could select two answers. It's very similar to Barmar's answer too :)

Comment: @xgrioux - I wrote this answer because at the time there were no other answers that return all the objects with the max length (which has been incorporated into other answers since then).  Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `filter` although it's nearly unreadable and cannot be called "good coding" with a clear conscious but when others can use `forEach` with a function instead of a simple loop without any good reason ... ;-)

```
JSON.stringify(
    orcs.sort(function(a,b){
        return b.weapons.length - a.weapons.length;
    }).filter(function(value,index,array){
        return value.weapons.length == array[0].weapons.length;
    })
)
```

Comment: This is a very cool way of finding an answer. But why did you put the reverse in?

Comment: Why did I...oh, typical C&P error, sorry. I forgot to `return` the result of the comparing function. Edited to correct.

Comment: "You have only 5 minutes to edit comments" *grrr*! So, again: The reason it worked in the first place: I added another Orc named "Blargh". The comparing function without a `return` got ignored, sorting was alphabetical, so "Blargh" comes before "Blaroguhh" (5th letters 'g' and 'o') and it needed the `reverse()` to be correct. Even experienced programmers are not immune from making quite embarrassing and stupid errors! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate into two functions, one to find the max, and one to find all orc with that max:

```
function getMostWeapons(allOrcs) {
    return allOrcs.reduce((max, currentOrc) => 
        Math.max(max, currentOrc.weapons.length), 0);
}

function getOrcsWithMostWeapons(allOrcs) {
    let maxWeapons = getMostWeapons(allOrcs);
    return allOrcs.filter(orc => orc.weapons.length === maxWeapons);
}
```

Note that this will return an array even if there's only one orc. I find it best to always return the same type.

Comment: Why use two passes when one will do?

Comment: @jfriend00 Because it really doesn't matter unless you have <100k orcs, and it's far far more readable this way. Still `O(n)`.

Comment: @jfriend00 It is by definition more readable. I have no `if`s, and for anyone who knows what `reduce` and `filter` is, you get super semantic code. For example, the code on the second function reads "Find the max weapons from that first function, then filter all orcs to find only those whose weapons length is equal to that". A forEach loop that needs to keep track of external scope is not as readable, even in this tiny example, imagine having to do it 3-4 scopes deep.

Comment: "More readable" is a definitely a matter of opinion.  It's not a factual conclusion.  I get that it is "your" opinion that this is more readable and you are free to offer your opinion on that.  Others may have different opinions.  And, btw, it's `2*O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var length=Math.max.apply(Math,orcs.map(function(o){return o.weapons.length;}));
var obj=orcs.find(function(x){ return x.weapons.length == length;}); // single object
var objList=orcs.filter(function(x){ return x.weapons.length == length;}); // multple
console.log(obj);
console.log(objList);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/y1zdntn0/3/)

Comment: `orcs.find` should be `orcs.filter`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Maybe it was before you added `.filter`, since he asked to return all the matching orcs, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but good if anyone comes here looking for a similar answer, I took the current answer and converted it to use for in, a little more generic too

```
function getLargest(o) {
var max = 0, maxObj = [];
for ( var item in o)
 {
    if (o[item].length > max) {
        max = o[item].length;
        maxObj = [item];
    } else if (o[item].length === max) {
        maxObj.push(item);
    }
};

return maxObj;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple loop with a length variable would probably be the best way

```
function getMostWeapons(orcs) {
   var len = 0; //longest
   for( x in orcs ){ //simple loop
      len = len < orcs[x].weapons.length ? orcs[x].weapons.length : len;
   }
}
```

Comment: This function doesn't return anything. It also doesn't remember which orc has the length in `len`, so it can't return it.